# Storing strings in android XML resource file and referencing them

Tags: android, xml

I'm wondering if I should use a resource XML file for to store all the possible recipes for me rather than using an ArrayList that is hardcoded, the problem is that I don't know how to call  from a resource file using the method i have...

Here is a cut down version of what I want:

```
int recipeNumber = b.getInt("RECIPE"); //This is taken from another activity

    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this); //Create a textview

    rowTextView.setText(R.string.recipeNumber); //This is what i am struggling with  

    howToLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView); //Add textview to linearlayout
```

I don't know what to put in the part that references my resource file. I know I need:
rowTextView.setText(R. but I'm not sure what would come after that.

Im storing strings that would be for example:

```
<string name="1">One part Vodka, One part Coke</string>
<string name="2">One part Vodka, One part Lemonade</string>
```

This list will be quite long so id appreciate any other suggestions on storage, bare in mind I'm pretty new to this.

The recipeNumber int is what string will be called in to the textview.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend storing the values outside your code, for example in XML or JSON (quicker and easier to work with).  I would go with JSON.  Really easy to load a list into an array, or other collection, and work with it anyway you want.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

You can then maintain your recipes, add new ones, maintain it etc without having to touch the code.  Simply replace the XML or JSON (or whatever you choose) and rebuild your app.

Strings.xml is intended for pieces of text in your UI and code which you might want to localise and to avoid hard coding strings.  It's not really intended for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

To get string resources in code, use getResources().

```
rowTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.recipeNumber));
```

---

To get an unknown resource identifier, but a known resource name, you can use the following method.

```
int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier("" + recipeNumber, "string", "com.your.package.name");
rowTextView.setText(getResources().getString(identifier));
```

Comment: It still doesn't recognise the recipeNumber part of it in my code - Its a variable so is there any way I can reference that?

Comment: You can get the identifier of a resource you know the name of.  See edit.